# Простой вывод цены детальная карточка/категория Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Такой момент: есть свой шаблон, в котором все стандартные компоненты в т.ч. каталог, в инфоблоках указано кто из них торг.каталог, в общем все стандартно, 1-а цена, 1-а валюта.
не пойму, чтобы вывести цену товара и кнопку в корзину в своем шаблоне, приходится брать заводской catalog.element / catalog.section и чистить от мусора вставляя свою верстку и т.д......... это жесть выходит.
print_r .... перепробовал все возможные сочетания с выводом arResult.
Задача: как можно проще вывести цену с работающей кнопкой в корзину.

Comment: Использовать готовые шаблоны, а не делать что-то свое не понимая что и как работает.

Comment: Спасибо, за очень полезный комментарий. Ничего посидел и разобрался. Уж лучше свое, а кому нравится использоваться шаблоны, пожалуйста.